# GetModuleFileName like APIs in WinRT

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'm writting a dll for windows phone 8, and need to know which module are calling my functions in dll. Howerver, the GetModuleFileName API is not compatible with WinRT. So is there any C++ API that is able to do the same thing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you export an interface let caller to register then you will know who call it?

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution. But I will have to change the interfaces, which will affect many existing modules. Thanks for concern. :)

Comment: Got you. I think the best way is to use Package query API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446597(v=vs.85).aspx